# Python скачивание изображений с BS4

Tags: python, изображения, requests, beautiful-soup

Код скачивает картинку и она занимает место, но при попытке открыть изображение становится 'ничем'...

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

link = input("Введите ссылку на ваш steam профиль: ")
r = requests.get(link)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
block = soup.find('div', class_='playerAvatarAutoSizeInner')

a = block.select('img')
b = a[1]

b1 = re.sub(r'<img src="', '',str(b), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
b2 = re.sub('"/>', '', str(b1), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(b2)
name = input('введите название картинки: ')
r_option = open(name + '.jpg', 'wb')
r_option.write(r.content)
r_option.close()
```

P.S. Скачивает аватарки со стима - ('https://steamcommunity.com/id/JA1KER/') пример для проверки

Comment: открой сохраненную "картинку" в текстовом редакторе и посмотри, что там на самом деле. Ты сохраняешь совсем не изображение

Comment: действительно :(, tam весь html код, есть варианты, kak можно сохранить именно изображение

Comment: есть конечно, надо загрузить содержимое ссылки, которая в b2 и потом сохранить :)

Answer (score 1):

```
img = requests.get(b2)
name = input('введите название картинки: ')
img_file = open(f"{name}.jpg", 'wb')
img_file.write(img.content)
img_file.close()
```

Залил решение